# default value for a class member in c++

Tags: c++

My code is as below: (Tried to made my original code simpler here)

```
class ExClass {

public:
  int check;
  ExClass() { }
}

//in main
int main()
{
  ExClass *classPtr = new ExClass();
  if(classPtr->check == -1)
  {
    cout<<"check is negative";
  }
}
```

Here the variable 'check' is not initialized in constructor, so it should take some garbage value(as I know).

But my problem here is, it is always printing "check is negative".(so 'check' is -1)

How this happens everytime ? How the variable 'check' is -1 always ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: `ExClass() : check(0) { }`

Comment: I really don't think you can rely on `check` always being `-1`. Looks like a bug waiting to happen. Just think that most probably the initialisation values for variables are compiler **and** platform dependent.

Comment: I think the value depends on your compiler. Here I'm using MinGW-w64 complier and it's a random number.

Comment: On a different compiler it will probably be a different value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `check` is what's called an [uninitialized variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable):

> A common assumption made by novice programmers is that all variables are set to a known value, such as zero, when they are declared. While this is true for many languages, it is not true for all of them, and so the potential for error is there. Languages such as C use stack space for variables, and the collection of variables allocated for a subroutine is known as a stack frame. While the computer will set aside the appropriate amount of space for the stack frame, it usually does so simply by adjusting the value of the stack pointer, and does not set the memory itself to any new state (typically out of efficiency concerns). Therefore, whatever contents of that memory at the time will appear as initial values of the variables which occupy those addresses.

This means the value isn't quite random. But more of a 'whatever the value of the thing before was' thing.

Also note that some compilers (such as visual c++) initialise uninitialised memory with magic numbers ([In Visual Studio C++, what are the memory allocation representations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)) while in debugging mode.